# remove country & state drop drop from Estimate Shipping and Tax

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to calculate Shipping price only on the basis of zip code. So I didn't want to show country as well as state drop down in "Estimate Shipping and Tax". Please help me how can I achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way suggested is that in phtml you populated those two fields and just hide those fields when displaying this form.

Comment: When I hide that fields than I am unable to submit form.

Comment: did you populate those fields so it had default values.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide what we populate these fields with and where. In the phtml or in the config?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a very old question, however adding the method we chose so that it can help someone in future.

**Note:**  This option will be useful if you have only one country where you ship to and State is not mandatory.

We tried to achieve this programmatically, but it was breaking functionality, also, unnecessary file changes were required. Also without country the zip code will not work, as zip code can be same across the countries, so we wrote CSS to hide the Country and State options.

Sample code below,

```
.checkout-cart-index div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"],
.checkout-cart-index div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] {
      display: none !important;
}
```

Since the ID of the country and state fields change dynamically, we referred to them from name of the div.

This is not an optimized solution, but a quick and safe one as it will not impact any functionality.